# Correct way to "compose" enums in Rust

Tags: rust

I'd like to be able to have a sum type that is either of two enums' members but am not sure if I'm doing this correctly. The idea would be for `Token` to be *either* a `Coordinate` or `AA` and for the `process_line` to return an array of `Token`s. Pretty basic. But do I have to wrap a `Token(...)` around every `Coordinate` or `AA` that I initialize for them to be such?

```rust
struct Coordinate {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    z: f64
}

enum AminoAcid {
    VAL, GLN ,ARG,
    LEU, THR ,TYR,
    SER, PRO ,CYS,
    GLY, ALA ,MET
}

enum Token {
    Coordinate(Coordinate),
    AminoAcid(AminoAcid)
}

// Want a function that returns a list of legal tokens given a &line.
fn _process_line(line:&str)->Vec<Token>{
    let token = Token::AminoAcid(AminoAcid::ARG);
    return vec![token];
}
```

For example, in typescript I could do

```js
type A = "Fur" | "Silver" | "Glass"
type B = "Leather" | "Wood"  | "Bronze"
type Material  = A | B;

var x: Material = "Wood" // is okay
```

whereas here I am having to do the whole `Material("Wood")` type of thing with

```rust
let token = Token::AminoAcid(AminoAcid::ARG);
let token = AminoAcid::ARG; // it would have been great to just have this, is this possible?
```

Comment: I think in rust this is the best way. That's only possible in typescript because of the dynamic typing. In rust unless it's behind a fat pointer the size of a type needs to be known at compile time so you can't just swap a coordinate for an amino acid and expect things to work.

Comment: No, statically typed Crystal also has anonymous product types aka enums.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement [`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) for each inner type. By implementing it you can call [`Into::into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html) on your inner types instances to get the outter enum representation:

```rust
struct Coordinate{
    x:f64,    y:f64,    z:f64
}

enum AminoAcid {
    VAL, GLN ,ARG,
    LEU, THR ,TYR,
    SER, PRO ,CYS,
    GLY, ALA ,MET
}

enum Token {
    Coordinate(Coordinate),
    AminoAcid(AminoAcid)
}

impl From<Coordinate> for Token {
    fn from(coord: Coordinate) -> Self {
        Self::Coordinate(coord)
    }
}

impl From<AminoAcid> for Token {
    fn from(aminoacid: AminoAcid) -> Self {
        Self::AminoAcid(aminoacid)
    }
}

// Want a function that returns a list of legal tokens given a &line.
fn _process_line(line:&str)->Vec<Token>{
    return vec![AminoAcid::ARG.into()];
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5e046b12cf478a9d3d887843d3cd6be7)